# How can I write a singleton resource in erlang nif?

Tags: erlang, resources, singleton

Is there a way to write a singleton class in c and then transferring it as a resource through NIF to erlang?

Comment: from my point of view, a registered erlang process is a singleton within a single node, if you need it for a cluster of nodes, then you should use the global library to register the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resources](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#resource_objects) are just pointers to memory. These pointers could be the direction of an instance of a class (as much of a singleton as you want it to be), thus sharing it with whoever has a copy of the resource or another resource pointing to the same memory.

Keep in mind the following:

1. Access to the memory should be synchronized, maybe using [mutexes](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_mutex_create) or [condition variables](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_cond_create).
2. Resources can be sent across nodes, but they are only relevant in the node that created it. If you try to derefernce a resource in another node, you'll get an error.
3. If a resource is left without references, it may be GC'd like any other term (you're able to provide a destructor). If a resource goes to another node and back, without saving a reference to the resource, it may have been collected.

Other than that creating the singleton is "as simple" as:

1. Initialize the memory during NIF module loading, storing it in the module's [priv data](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_priv_data)
2. Create [resources](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#resource_objects) pointing to that memory, use the resources as you want
3. Access the resource memory through proper synchronization methods